# How to combine two messages with data retrieved from the MySQL db in Apache Camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel, integration

I'm currently working on an integration project. I have to get some data from the MySQL database and them combine them using Apache Camel. In the database I've got two tables, materials and packages. They are in the one-to-many relation, one material can contain multiple packages. I've already figured out how to get data from the database and save them to json file, but I have no idea how to combine those two messages into one. I've read about Aggregations but I don't really get them. This is my first usage of Apache Camel and I don't really know what sould I do now. The code for those routes looks like this:

```
public class InputAdapter{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Packages");
    dataSource.setUsername("uname");
    dataSource.setPassword("passwd");
    SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
    registry.bind("dataSource", dataSource);

    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() {
            from("timer://foo?repeatCount=1")
                    .setBody(constant("SELECT * FROM material;"))
                    .to("jdbc:dataSource")
                    .marshal().json(true)
                    .to("file:/some/path/to/file?fileName=materials.json");
            from("timer://foo?repeatCount=1")
                    .setBody(constant("SELECT * FROM package;"))
                    .to("jdbc:dataSource")
                    .marshal().json(true)
                    .to("file:/some/path/to/file?fileName=packages.json");
        }
    });

    context.start();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    context.stop();
}
}
```

And the model for Material and a Package are just private properties with getters and setters:

```
public class Material {
private int id;
private int number;
private enumType type;
private String name;
private String description;
private boolean is_deleted;
private List<Package> packageList = new ArrayList<>();

public enum enumType {
    A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, Z1, Z2, Z3;
}

public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}

... some getters
}

public List<Package> getPackageList() {
    return this.packageList;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

... some setters

public void setPackageList(List<Package> packages) {
    this.packageList = packages;
}
}
```

Can someone give me a hint what sould I do now? Please help me.

Comment: If the tables are in the same database, then you can execute a single SQL SELECT statement that joins them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregators are normally used to combine messages coming in from a source. I probably wouldn't use the aggregators to combine these two sets of items. If you're looking to pull all the Materials and get the associated packages from the database, you might be better to retrieve the list of packages per Material.

I would create a Processor that handles retrieving the packages for each of the returned Materials objects and then output the whole thing in a single route.

You can define a processor class in Camel like so:

```
public class PackageProcessor implements Processor {
  @Override
  public void process(Exchange exchange) {
    // Transform the input to your message class
    // Retrieve the Packages
    // Transform the results to Packages
    // Add to the Material
    // Set the Out Body
    exchange.getMessage().setBody(material);
  }
}
```

You can then use the processor in your Route to do this work. That would make the route look something like this then:

```
from("timer://foo?repeatCount=1")
  .routeId("my-material-route")
  .setBody(constant("SELECT * FROM materials;"))
  .to("jdbc:dataSource")
  .split(body())
  .process(new PackageProcessor())
  .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, simple("${exchangeId}.json"))
  .marshal().json(true)
  .to("file:/somepath")
  .end();
```

This would output each record to a Json file with the needed information. If you want all of the items to be placed in a single file, this is where an aggregator would come into play.

You'll notice a couple of items in the route outside of your original. The result of the JDBC component is an ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>.  We add a Split in the route to send each item separately into the processor instead of the entire result set. The processor should receive a HashMap<String, Object> in the Exchange Body.

After the processor, we set the CamelFileName Header on the exchange to the Exchange Id and this will then output an individual file per record from the Materials table.

If you want to have it all in a single file, you can use an Aggregator that will collect the exchanges and build a list. That might be a little more complicated to have it release the exchanges out to a JSON file.  You normally have to set a timeout or some sort of evaluation function to figure out when the "super" exchange should be released.